# Pause Video When Not In Sight in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, html5-video

I have a problem pausing the video when not in view. I have successfully paused it when switching to different slider.
I also need to unload or how do you prevent it from running in the background when not playing so it might browser will not be loaded.

Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/video-player-with-slider-forked-comoz?file=/src/Player.js:458-794)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      root: document.querySelector("#video"),
      threshold: 0.1
    };
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio !== 1) {
          setPlayed(false);
        }
      });
    }, options);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/video-player-with-slider-forked-5th85?file=/src/visibleHook.js) to check I have fixed your code now video is pausing when not in the sight.
Just added a hook to check whether the player is in dom or not and according to this managing state

```
const isVisible = useOnScreen(videoRef);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlayed(isVisible);
  }, [isVisible]);

 <div ref={videoRef}  className="react-player-wrapper">
      <ReactPlayer
        playsinline={true}
        playing={played}
        ....
         
        light={    "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/875749462957670400/T0lwiBK8_400x400.jpg"
        }
      />
```

And hook used to check player is visible or not

```
 import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";
    export default function useOnScreen(ref) {
      const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false)
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        ([entry]) => setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting)
      )

      useEffect(() => {
            observer.observe(ref.current)
        return () => { observer.disconnect() }
      }, [])
    
      return isIntersecting
    }
```

Comment: It has error. pls check again. Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: Please provide the code changes required to understand your answer without relying on external links.

Comment: make sure you provide ref of outer div of ReactPlayer not react player that is causing error and my codesandbox is working fine

Comment: @Abhi. Pls check your codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/video-player-with-slider-forked-5th85?file=/src/Player.js. It has error here

Comment: check now I forgot to save code in sand box

Comment: ok. video is not playing automatically when first loaded? and then it does't play automatic when change slides? It should start automatic just like in my codesandbox

Comment: You are right I modified your code to fix your problem you can easily fix this by adding old code along side this